# Writing a custom HSQLDialect to change Hibernate return type for uniqueResult()

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate method uniqueResult() to get the count of records in a table

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM TABLE";
```

In tests we use HSQLDB in-memory or localhost databases and uniqueResult() returns a java.math.BigInteger for count(*). But in the real environment we use DB2 where uniqueResult() returns java.lang.Integer. So when I run my tests I get a ClassCastException `java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` on the following code:

```
SQLQuery q = getSession(false).createSQLQuery(query);
Integer count = (Integer) q.uniqueResult();
```

There is a fix I found to specify the return type by adding the addScalar() method:

```
SQLQuery q = getSession(false).createSQLQuery(query).addScalar("C", Hibernate.INTEGER);
```

But is there a way I can make the default behavior for the return type change across the board? Perhaps by writing a custom HSQLDialect that would specify all count values be returned as an Integer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `select count(somecolumn)` instead of `select count(*)`. You may find the data type returned is the same type for both databases. I think the returned type is related to the type of the column used in the count expression.

Comment: hm, it still seems to return a BigInteger, I'm getting the same error. Also, I would prefer to keep the * in there since our column names can change unfortunately. Even when I do count(1) it still comes back as a BigInteger

Comment: Use could try casting to java.lang.Number and then use intValue or longValue method.

Comment: Ok so this works, thank you. The problem though is that it's similar to the fix i found where you add "addScalar()" in that it requires you to modify your code strictly for testing purposes. I read it's bad practice to "code to your tests".

So I was actually looking for a way to tweak just the test code so that it can handle the production code instead of vice versa. Maybe tweaking the dialect could do it, but that's unfamiliar territory for me.